# segfault when printing the third string in a parse tree

Tags: c, string, tree, segmentation-fault, unions

I am creating a compiler, and beginning to create my parse tree structure.

I have this for a 'node' which can contain subnodes, or not.

```
typedef struct Node {
    int node_type;
    union {
        char* string;
        int number;
        struct Node* nodes;
    } node_data;
} Node;
```

And these functions assemble/print it

```
Node* MakeNodeFromString(char* mystring) {
    Node* mynode = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    mynode->node_data.string = strdup(mystring);
    mynode->node_type = 0; // @TODO not 3
    return mynode;
}

Node* MakeTwoBranchNode(int nodetype, Node* a, Node* b) {
    Node* mynode = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    mynode->node_type = 2; // @TODO not 3
    mynode->node_data.nodes = malloc(2 * sizeof(Node*));
    mynode->node_data.nodes[0] = *a; mynode->node_data.nodes[1] = *b;
    return mynode;
}

void printtree (Node *n, int level) {
    if (!n) return;

    printf ("start %d\n", n->node_type);
    switch (n->node_type) {
        case 2:
            printf ("%*c2\n", level, ' ');
            printtree (&n->node_data.nodes[0], level+1);
            printtree (&n->node_data.nodes[1], level+1);
            break;
        case 0:
            printf ("%*c%s\n", level, ' ', n->node_data.string);
            break;
    }
    printf ("end %d\n", n->node_type);
}
```

And whenever I assemble a tree I get segfaults either printf'ing or strlen'ing my strings. I've tried strdup, strcpy, etc. I'm pretty sure its not MakeTwoBranchNode that's failing because I can create large trees of numbers (code not included). But I'm not sure.

This is a codesample of where it does - and doesnt - segfault on my machine

```
int main() {
    // Works
    printtree(
        MakeTwoBranchNode(3,
            MakeNodeFromString("first string"),
            MakeNodeFromString("second string")
        ),
        1
    );
    // Fails
    printtree(
        MakeTwoBranchNode(3,
            MakeTwoBranchNode(3,
                MakeNodeFromString("first string"),
                MakeNodeFromString("second string")
            ),
            MakeNodeFromString("third string")
        ),
        1
    );
}
```

If you run this example (and can understand its cryptic output) you'll see it segfaults during printf(n->node_data.string).

Comment: I would prefer: `struct Node *nodes[2];` as a (tree type) member, but if you insist: it should be `struct Node **nodes;` (your compiler should issue a warning for this)

Comment: @wildplasser likewise. It would make for a much cleaner implementation as well.

Comment: Since this is a parser, eventually I will flatten the tree so that, for instance, the program becomes Node with node_data->Nodes to be all the program's statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're allocating sizeof-a-pointer, not sizeof-a-node in the following:

```
Node* MakeTwoBranchNode(int nodetype, Node* a, Node* b) {
    Node* mynode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    mynode->node_type = 2; // @TODO not 3
    mynode->node_data.nodes = malloc(2 * sizeof(Node*)); // HERE
    mynode->node_data.nodes[0] = *a; mynode->node_data.nodes[1] = *b;
    return mynode;
}
```

You could change the commented line above to:

```
    mynode->node_data.nodes = malloc(2 * sizeof(Node));
```

However, as written your test program as a memory leak. What happens to the memory you allocated for the nodes your *passing* to `MakeTwoBranchNode()`? This is not what I think you *really* want. You wold be better off using a pointer-array in the first place.

```
typedef struct Node {
    int node_type;
    union {
        char* string;
        int number;
        struct Node *nodes[2];
    } node_data;
} Node;
```

Then save the actual *pointers* passed to `MakeTwoBranchNode`. In doing so you're passing *ownership* of those nodes to the two-branch node (and thus you should also ensure when it is freed it properly cleans up its child nodes):

```
Node* MakeTwoBranchNode(int nodetype, Node* a, Node* b) {
    Node* mynode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    mynode->node_type = 2; // @TODO not 3
    mynode->node_data.nodes[0] = a; 
    mynode->node_data.nodes[1] = b;
    return mynode;
}
```

Now there's no memory leak unless you fail to `free()` the pointers in `nodes[0]` and `nodes[1]` when you're destroying the two-branch node.

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef struct Node {
    int node_type;
    union {
        char *string;
        int number;
        struct Node **nodes; // <-- here
    } node_data;
} Node;


Node *MakeNodeFromString(char *mystring) {
    Node *mynode = malloc(sizeof *mynode);
    mynode->node_data.string = strdup(mystring);
    mynode->node_type = 0; // @TODO not 3
    return mynode;
}

Node *MakeTwoBranchNode(int nodetype, Node *a, Node *b) {
    Node *mynode = malloc(sizeof *mynode);
    mynode->node_type = 2; // @TODO not 3
    mynode->node_data.nodes = malloc(2 * sizeof *mynode->node_data.nodes ); // <- here
    mynode->node_data.nodes[0] = *a; mynode->node_data.nodes[1] = *b;
    return mynode;
}

void printtree (Node *n, int level) {
    if (!n) return;

    printf ("start %d\n", n->node_type);
    switch (n->node_type) {
        case 2:
            printf ("%*c2\n", level, ' ');
            printtree (n->node_data.nodes[0], level+1); // <-- here
            printtree (n->node_data.nodes[1], level+1); // <- and here
            break;
        case 0:
            printf ("%*c%s\n", level, ' ', n->node_data.string);
            break;
    }
    printf ("end %d\n", n->node_type);
}
```